# How do I collapse an Expander whenever the DataGrid inside is null using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some code like this

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding HasData}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDataSource}">
        <!-- some sode -->
    </DataGrid>
</Expander>
```

Right now I am programmatically setting `HasData` to `true` whenever `SomeDataSource` is set to something not null.

Is it possible to achieve this using just XAML, without any c# code?

Comment: Use a converter in the is expanded binding

Comment: Instead of HasData, you could probably bind to the HasItems property of the DataGrid and use a converter like suggested above

Comment: @failedprogramming whats the difference?

Comment: The difference is you don't have to programmatically set HasData.

Comment: Also, you won't need a converter if you can change your logic to: "Expander is only expanded when datagrid has items"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a DataTrigger and save yourself the converter.

```
<Expander>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeDataSource, ConverterParameter=SomeData}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use a converter to bind to `SomeDataSource` too:

```
public class IsNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            return value == null;
        else
            return value != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, you can use it in XAML only:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <l:IsNullConverter x:Key="IsNullConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding SomeDataSource, Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}, ConverterParameter=SomeData}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDataSource}">
        <!-- some sode -->
    </DataGrid>
</Expander>
```

**EDIT**
If it is no problem in your case, you can also bind to the `DataGrid.HasItems` property. It determines, if there are items in the source list. But it collapses the Expander too, when the source contains no items, but it is not `null` (source is an empty list).

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding HasItems, ElementName=dg, Mode=OneWay}">
    <DataGrid Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDataSource}">
        <!-- some sode -->
    </DataGrid>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `DataTrigger` with an `Expander` `Style` and binding to the `DataGrid` itself works.

```
    <Expander>
        <Expander.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=ItemsSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Expander.Style>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDataSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <!-- some code -->
        </DataGrid>
    </Expander>
```